# self.__class__.__bases__ doesn't trace back to class object

Tags: python, class

Perhaps this is a trivial question.  under python, how come `self.__class__.__bases__` doesn't trace back to `object`?  Mine only shows a tuple of the one single parent above the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__bases__`essentially contains the base-classes passed to the metaclass constructor.

So a class definition statement like:

```
class Foo(Bar, Baz):
    pass
```

Is essentially equivalent to:

```
Foo = type("Foo", (Bar, Baz), {})
```

So the `__bases__` attribute is essentially the value to the `bases` argument of the `type` constructor: `type(object_or_name, bases, dict)`

If you want the entire inheritance chain, you should use:

```
self.__class__.mro()
```

To read a little bit more about the internals of class creating, read about metaclasses, [section 3.3.3.1 to 3.3.3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)

Answer (score 7):

`self.__class__.__bases__` only goes "one level up" in class inheritance. If you want to trace all the way through every parent class up to `object`, use `self.__class__.__mro__`.

Comment: yes, the __mro__ worked great.  just what i was looking for.  thank you.